# Test if hosting supports mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, hosting, web-hosting

I have asked my hosting company and they said "yes, we support .net4/mvc3" However, I am not convinced since my hellomvc test app does not return the home/index route as it does on my local machine.

Dev: shows /hello/index
Hosting: shows Directory listing denied

Back in the classic asp days a little Response.Write would tell you that ASP was working.

Have I completed my test before I contact my hosting company again, or is there something more specific i can try?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hosting company only needs to have a version of ASP .NET installed which is compatible with MVC. MVC itself can be deployed by simply copying the required assemblies into the bin folder of your application.

(It can also optionally be installed into the GAC on the server which would allow multiple web applications to share the same assemblies and give you a small saving on space, and maintainablity but this is just one option)

Martin

EDIT:

The only thing I can think of which might stop a basic MVC website working on any ASP.NET hosting is if the server is not running in integrated mode i.e. it only maps the asp .net extensions to the asp .net handler, [you may need to configure routing to use urls ending in .aspx](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-vb)

Comment: Using the /home/index.aspx method. I was able to see a config error showing .net4 is not recognized (showing the web.config line). I can now go back to the hosting company with this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try hosting a sample MVC App, built by MSFT.